# Swift image positioning inside scrollview get cropped

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have an image inside a scroll view (which is inside a view). Half of the image is actually positioned outside the scrollview and it got cropped.

Is t possibile to show the image on top of everything?
[image]

So far i have tried:

```
imageView.layer.zPosition = 1
imageView.superview.bringSubview(toFront: imageView)
```

my structure is the following:
MainView
 Safe area
 BackgroundImage
  ScrollView
   imageView
   View

Thank you!

Comment: Is clipsToBounds or masksToBounds set to true for the scrollview?

Comment: @Sparky you just got it! ahah! i tried everything but checking the obvious.... :) clip to bounds were set to true in the scrollView...Setting it to false fixed it! Thx!